# Нарежь хлеба или хлеб?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно: "нарежь **хлеба**" или "нарежь **хлеб**", "налей **сока**" или "налей **сок**", "добавь **соли и перца**" или "добавь **соль и перец**"?

Comment: Назвался груздем — полезай в кузов, а назвался учителем —  начинай предложение с прописной и не заканчивай запятой. (Вышло в рифму)

Comment: @М_Г, уже внес эти исправления в вопрос, теперь жду прохождения "экспертной проверки".

Answer (score 2):

Правильны обе конструкции, но есть смысловое различие.

"Нарежь хлеба" - это нарежь сколько-нибудь, например имея в виду число едоков,

а "нарежь хлеб" - это всё имеющееся в наличии, весь хлеб, предназначенный к трапезе.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы подразумеваете : немного хлеба, то есть, "нарежь немного хлеба", опуская слово " немного", тогда - "нарежь хлеба". А если хлеб следует нарезать, например, ломтями, то -  "нарежь хлеб". С соком, солью и перцем почти то же самое - "немного сока, соли, перца"... Но : "налей сок в стакан, соль перец добавь в суп".